# Ubuntu wired network disconnected

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, local-area-network, wired

I am not able to establish a wired network connection between two computers on which I just installed Ubuntu 10.04.

I am new to this environment. Unlike in the Windows environment, where it happens by just connecting them with a cable, Ubuntu keeps flashing a notification saying "Wired network disconnected".  Am I missing a driver or something?

I *am* able to connect to the wi-fi router without issue. The *wired* connection is just not working.

Comment: Has the two machines assigned ip addresses of the same range? Say like: 92.168.1.34 and 192.168.1.35. Are you able to ping one from the other?

Comment: Are you using a cross-over cable, or do you have a switch or hub in-between?

Comment: Thanks..@Ajo Augustine: after i read your reply i tried to assign static ip addresses to both the systems but got stuck on what should be the DNS server. IP Addresses: 192.168.2.7 and 192.168.2.8; Netmask: 255.255.255.0; Gateway:192.168.2.0; Don't know what should the DNS server be. any suggestion please? @Ewan Leith: I am using a cross-over cable.

Comment: you don't need a DNS server to connect them. But you can always use some free dns servers (like [google's 8.8.8.8](http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/speed/public-dns/))

Comment: Thanks a lot Ajo, Ewan, Pconcepcion, Jscott :) i just assigned static IP's with DNS server as suggested above and got it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just assign some static IPs and you'll be on your way.

Answer (score 0):

In **/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf**,change **managed=false** to **managed=true**.

After that type in terminal

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```